# How to escape backticks in knitr?

Tags: r, knitr

I have a variable named `statistical value of life in millions of 2006 dollars`, and I'm trying to include the value in inline knitr code.

```
`r `statistical value of life in millions of 2006 dollars` `
```

I can't figure out how to escape the backticks.

Comment: Adding a bounty to this question to get a non-workaround answer. My use case is when you have something like: `library(dplyr);dat %>% select(myvar) %>% ~[[~(1)` (substitute backticks for ~). I can just write a function to do that last bit, but it would be nice since backticks are core R functionality.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman  assuming you've defined `myvar` earlier, does this give the result you want: `\`r dat %>% .[[myvar]]\``, or am I not understanding what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to use another way of addressing the variable:

```
`r get('statistical value of life in millions of 2006 dollars')`
```

Comment: In R, the easiest solution would be to not have a verbose variable name. `x` is popular, I hear. :)

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Well sure but there’s generally nothing wrong in R with using names that (a) contain spaces, or (b) are otherwise invalid identifiers. And it’s not inconceivable that there are real use-cases where somebody legitimately needs to use such a name in Knitr. I myself regularly use pretty names for table columns — nobody in their right mind wants to read tables in a publication with column header such as “log2foldChange” (a common occurrence in my field).

Comment: I've run into this recently too when trying to make a table pretty. I made nice variable names for reading and then needed to do something with them. Didn't know about get()... seems useful.

Comment: For me these long variable names are not for "self documenting" purposes, I use them frequently automate label making in plots and column headers in html rendered tables.

Comment: Using `get()` is a nice workaround, but a direct answer to the question "How to escape backticks in knitr?" would also be interesting, I think.

Comment: @geneorama & @Konrad Rudoplh : My approach for producing tables is to use short yet descriptive column/row names right up until the point where I want to actually produce the output table, and just before I do I use `names()` to then change the names to something that will look nice and be easily readable/recognisable.  In the long run it saves a *lot* of typing in writing scripts.

Comment: @slackline Fair enough but “saves typing” isn’t a relevant argument in programming. Typing is a minuscule fraction of the overall time you spend in programming, optimising this fraction doesn’t yield any tangible overall benefit (and if you want to optimise typing, invest in learning a proper editor instead, i.e. Emacs or Vim). Optimise *readability* instead.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I've been using Emacs for about a decade thanks.  I still find in R that using shorter names when writing code preferable to having to deal with escaping spaces in variable names.

Comment: @slackline I find that defending my choices such as long or short variable names on SO makes me feel perpetually trolled

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Similarly, I find that my energy spent composing responses on lists or SO is both as exhausting as programming, and as painful as typing.

Comment: @geneorama Neither is superior to another.  Perhaps you might consider it an explanation of why _I_ choose to do something in a particular way rather than a request/demand for _you_ to defend your choice.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps consider using a name without spaces in it (and a little shorter).